# JQuery get every image with 100px or more width

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the length of every image with `100px` or more of `width`:

```
if( $('img').width( >= 100 ).length > 0 ){
   [MORE CODE]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    if( $(this).width() >= 100 ){
       [MORE CODE]
    }
});
```

Comment: @AmmarCSE Sure. Done buddy. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like

```
$('img').filter(function(){
    return $(this).width() >= 100;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter()` to achieve this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $imgs = $('img').filter(function() {
        return $(this).width() >= 100;
    });

    // do something with $imgs...
});
```

Note that you should execute this under the `window.load` event to ensure that the `img` elements have loaded and therefore have a set width.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('img').each(function() {
     if($(this).width() >= 100) {
         // more code
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `outerWidth` to determine:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $imgs = $('img').filter(function() {
        return $(this).outerWidth() >= 100;
    });

    // do something with $imgs...
});
```

Comment: Why use outerWidth(), is it to take padding into account?

Comment: Yup... `padding` and `margin`.